# Protected attributes in classmethod

Tags: python, attributes, class-method, pylint

Python conventions suggest to proceed the names of protected attributes with an underscore. As far as I understand protected attributes should only be used within a given class and its subclasses. Could you then provide me with some intuition on why pylint returns *protected-access* warnings when I try to use protected attributes inside alternative initializers, e.g.

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self._count = 0
        self._bound = 1  # max value

    @classmethod
    def specific_state(cls, name, bound):
        test = cls(name)
        test._bound = bound
```

I do understand that in this specific case (presented in the example above) I work on an instance of an object but it is still inside the class definition thus it seems ok from my point of view. Is pylint a bit too rigorous in this matter or do I misunderstand sth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `pylint.checkers.classes.ClassChecker` in the `_check_protected_attribute_access` method:

```
'''Given an attribute access node (set or get), check if attribute
access is legitimate. Call _check_first_attr with node before calling
this method. Valid cases are:
* self._attr in a method or cls._attr in a classmethod. Checked by
_check_first_attr.
* Klass._attr inside "Klass" class.
* Klass2._attr inside "Klass" class when Klass2 is a base class of
    Klass.
'''
```

You can see that your case in not among the mentioned cases. So one could assume that the `protected-access` warning is legit.

But:

1. from `pylint`s code itself the exact same case occurred. (e.g. exceptions.py:338):

   ```
   # pylint: disable=protected-access
   exc = exc._proxied
   ```

   So basically they disabled their on checker in that case.
2. in c++ the following code is valid:

   ```
           class X
   {
   private:
       int a;
   protected:
       int b;
   public:
       static void staticMethod(X& x)
       {
           x.a = 1;
           x.b = 1;
       }
   };
   ```

   So accessing protected/private members in static methods is valid.

I would say that `pylint` is overly sensitiv in this case. You could use a comment to disable the checker there. The reason that the warning is produced is probably that it is kind of hard for a static checker to implement a more complex behavior.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, `pylint` is too vigorous on this one.  I doubt that there would be too much disagreement on this.  I can't speak for the pylint developers, but I would *guess* that this is more of a problem with the type inferencing than necessarily being considered their ideal behavior.

---

Different people will probably tell you different opinions on referencing members that lead with an underscore.  My *personal* opinion is that

- **If it is in the same module, it's fair game**

  - however, you should still strive to limit this as much as possible to avoid tying class/function implementations together where possible.
- **If the member belongs to a different module, it is no longer fair game and should be treated as an implementation detail.**

  - tying the implementations together here is inherently dangerous as changes to one implementation could easily break the other code without warning.

So this means that if I have class `Foo` (with member `_member`) defined in `foo.py` and if I make a subclass of `Foo` (lets call it `Bar`) in `bar.py`, I don't believe that `Bar` should make any explicit reference to the `_member` attribute.  However, if you move `Bar` into `foo.py`, then it's Ok.  In fact, class `Baz` (also defined in `foo.py`) should also be allowed to rely on the internals of `Foo` -- but it better have a good reason for doing so.

Mostly, I'm not OK with the treatment of underscore prefixed members as "protected" (in the Java sense).  I think they are meant to be treated as "implementation details".  Protected works a lot better in Java because if you change the implementation (e.g. remove a protected member), the code will fail at compile time and let you know that the protected member your subclass relies on is no longer there.  Python has no such safe-guards built in.

Because underscore prefixed names are "implementation details", if it's the same class (like the situation you describe in your question), then it's the same implementation and so (to me) allowing access to those members is a no-brainer.  I'd `# pylint: disable=protected-access` that without a second thought :-).